# YAML check if param exists

Tags: python, yaml, travis-ci

I have a .yml file for travis-ci in a Python app testing:

```
...
matrix:
 include:
  - env: BUILD_DOCS=true
    python: '2.7'
before_install:
- test -z "$BUILD_DOCS" || openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_key -iv $encrypted_iv
  -in keypair.enc -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa -d
- test -z "$BUILD_DOCS" || chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This works when build is triggered on GitHub inside the original repository. However, when I make a pull request from my fork, it breaks due to those encrypted params not being accessible for my fork.

All I need to do is add a check if they exist and skip that part if they do not exists. But I have no clue how to do it, this is the first time I've opened a YAML file. I've tried googling, but didn't find a solution.

This is the error:

```
$ test -z "$BUILD_DOCS" || openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_key -iv $encrypted_iv -in keypair.enc -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa -d
iv undefined

The command "test -z "$BUILD_DOCS" || openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_key -iv $encrypted_iv -in keypair.enc -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa -d" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

From what I've heard so far, this should be pretty easy to fix, but I don't know the syntax. Anyone has experience with this?

Comment: I think you'll need to do some checking in the test files. Perhaps `if not os.getenv('encrypted_key'): error_handling_here()`

Comment: It's not an error if it doesn't exist. It should just skip that part if encrypted part does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case a different troubled soul stumbles on this problem in the future, I've managed to solve it today.

Travis has a convenience variable that helps here:

```
TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST is set to the pull request number if the current job is a pull request build, or false if it’s not.
```

So, I've used that along with the if syntax that works in .yml files. I don't know if this is the best solution, but it worked for me.

This is my changed code:

```
matrix:
  include:
   - env: BUILD_DOCS=true
     python: '2.7'
 before_install:
- if [ $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == 'false' ]; then
    test -z "$BUILD_DOCS" || openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_key -iv $encrypted_iv -in keypair.enc -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa -d;
    test -z "$BUILD_DOCS" || chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa;
  fi
```